# How do I take a date and extract the day in iOS"

Tags: ios, date

I have a webservice that returns the date in this format:

```
2013-04-14
```

How do i figure out what day this corresponds to?

Comment: have you ever looked into the documentation of `NSDate` ?

Comment: When you say you want the day, do you mean the 14th or do you mean Sunday (in the case of April 14, 2013).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternate method for getting the weekday can be:

```
NSString *myDateString = @"2013-04-14";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

NSInteger weekday = [components weekday];
NSString *weekdayName = [dateFormatter weekdaySymbols][weekday - 1];

NSLog(@"%@ is a %@", myDateString, weekdayName);
```

Answer (score 11):

This code will take your string, convert it to an NSDate object and extract both the number of the day (14) and the name of the day (Sunday)

```
NSString *myDateString = @"2013-04-14";

// Convert the string to NSDate
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];

// Extract the day number (14)
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [components day];

// Extract the day name (Sunday)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE";
NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

// Print
NSLog(@"Day: %d: Name: %@", day, dayName);
```

Note: This code is for ARC.  If MRC, add [dateFormatter release] at the end.

Comment: Consider removing the reference to the other answer. This is a good answer and can stand on its own.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code it working for me.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-04-14";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `2013-04-14` stored in a `NSString` called `date`, then you can do this...

```
NSArray *dateComponents = [date componentsSeperatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *day = [dateComponents lastObject];
```

Comment: I do but i get the day's date...so instead of Thursday (today) i get the 11th... :)

Comment: See my answer for how to show the name of the day (eg. Sunday)

Answer (score 0):

### **Swift 3:**

---

```
let datFromat = DateFormatter()

datFormat.dateFormat = "EEEE"

let name = datFormat.string(from: Date())
```

**Bonus**: If you want to set your own date template instead of using `Date()` above:

```
let datFormat = DateFormatter()

datFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

let thisDate = datFormat.date(from: "2016-10-13T18:00:00-0400")
```

Then call the 1st code after this.