# How to get date and weekday from standard time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want to know the weekday from this `2017-01-01T23:33:09+0800` format of time which I have in a string , so I can compare current date and show it like yesterday, today ,Monday etc.

Comment: Swift 2.0 ya 3.0 ?

Comment: Check this. Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/15962241/6271729

Comment: still on objective c

Comment: @vishwasparashar do you need solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *myDateString = @"2017-01-11T23:33:09+0800";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"]; // you have to set your dateformatter according your requirement.
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];

NSInteger weekday = [components weekday];
NSString *weekdayName = [dateFormatter weekdaySymbols][weekday - 1];

// here you get your date day like sunday , monday , etc.   
NSLog(@"%@ is a %@", myDateString, weekdayName);

// check for your date is today , yesterday or Tommorow.

NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
if ([calender isDateInToday:date1]) {
        NSLog(@"Today");
}
else if ([calender isDateInYesterday:date1])
{
        NSLog(@"Yesterday");
}else if([calender isDateInTomorrow:date1]){
        NSLog(@"Tommorow");
}
```

**Output :**

```
2017-01-11T23:33:09+0800 is a Wednesday
Yesterday
```

Comment: can its be like 'Yesterday at 10:30 pm'?

Comment: [calender isDateInYesterday:date1] this condition only return true or false as your question i give you perfect solution @vishwasparashar

Comment: 10:30 pm @vishwasparashar how can you set this like fix time ?

Comment: I am getting these string from server in a array, each string have different time

Comment: then you have to perform this in else if ([calender isDateInYesterday:date1])
{ } condition. and you can set it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is swift 3.0 code for converting DateString to `weekDay` :

```
let myDateString = "2017-01-01T23:33:09+0800"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: myDateString)!
let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.weekday])
var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: date)
let weekday = components.weekday!
let weekdayName = dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[weekday - 1]
print("\(myDateString) is a \(weekdayName)")
```

**Output:**
2017-01-01T23:33:09+0800 is a Sunday

Hope this helps you.